# HDFS File Comparison

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

How can I compare two HDFS files since there is no `diff`?

I was thinking of using Hive tables and loading data from HDFS and then using join statements on 2 tables. Is there any better approach?

Comment: What version of hadoop are you using? Are you using a CDH distro?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no `diff` command provided with hadoop, but you can actually use redirections in your shell with the `diff` command:

```
diff <(hadoop fs -cat /path/to/file) <(hadoop fs -cat /path/to/file2)
```

If you just want to know if 2 files are identical or not without caring to know the differences, I would suggest another checksum-based approach: you could get the checksums for both files and then compare them. I think Hadoop doesn't need to generate checksums because they are already stored so it should be fast, but I may be wrong. I don't think there's a command line option for that but you could easily do this with the Java API and create a small app:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
chksum1 = fs.getFileChecksum(new Path("/path/to/file"));
chksum2 = fs.getFileChecksum(new Path("/path/to/file2"));
return chksum1 == chksum2;
```

Comment: I want to compare two hdfs directory , one has compacted data (4 files) and other has 50 files uncompacted, how to compare directories...

Comment: The checksum may be different if the block sizes are different even for the same file.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the simplest answer is probably:

```
diff <(hadoop fs -cat file1) <(hadoop fs -cat file2)
```

It will just run on your local machine. If that's too slow, then yes, you'd have to do something with Hive and MapReduce, but that's a little trickier, and won't exactly match the in-order comparison that diff does.