# How to compare sizes of the files inside 2 directories are same inside hdfs location using python or shell?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have two directories in hdfs. when i am executing `hadoop ls` command

my first  directory:

```
 $hadoop fs -ls /data/
-rw-r--r--   3 test test   258055811 2020-03-06 10:45 /data/log.cat
-rw-r--r--   3 test test   253135376 2020-03-06 10:45 /data/log0.cat
 -rw-r--r--   3 test test   2531353 2020-03-06 10:45 /data/log1.cat
```

my second directory :

```
   $hadoop fs -ls /data1/
    -rw-r--r--   3 test test   258055811 2020-03-06 10:45 /data1/log.cat
    -rw-r--r--   3 test test   253135376 2020-03-06 10:45 /data1/log0.cat
-rw-r--r--   3 test test   2531353 2020-03-06 10:45 /data1/log1.cat
```

now I want compare file sizes inside both directory are the same or not i.e. files  inside data and data1  sizes are same .

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14491669/361089

Comment: If you pasted real data from your shell, it seems that the directory si remote and therefore both directories should be the same.

If you look at both outputs of the files, there is the same path.

Comment: i have changed my question  directories is different path 1)data 2)data1 directory..